# No reconoce el UsersController

Tags: php, laravel

[![ReflectionException (-1)
Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController does not exist][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6htIA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6htIA.png)

Alguien sabe por que no me reconoce el controller?
acabo de crear la carpeta admin, agregué el "Admin/" como dice la documentación pero me tira este error :

Class App\Http\Controllers\Admin\UsersController does not exist

Comment: Envía una imagen de tu árbol de carpetas posterior a eso también tus rutas, no creo que sea problema de psr4, aclara como estas haciendo el uso del controlador. agrega un poco mas de información porque así como la pones hay muchas razones para ese error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolvi, el proceso era sencillo:
1 - Agregar el "\Admin" al Route
    (Admin\UsersController@procesar)
2 - Agregar el "\Admin" al namespace del controller 
    (namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;)
3 - Agregar "use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;" dentro del UserController

Con eso queda resuelto el problema.

Answer (score 0):

PAra la proxima intenta poner tambien ejemplos de lo que tienes.

Tienes que agregarlo al `classmap` del archivo composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "Admin",
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
```

Y ahora ya puedes usarlos

Comment: ya lo agregue pero sigo teniendo problemas

Comment: "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "app/http/controllers/admin"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
        }
    },

Comment: que namespace usas en el controller?

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

Comment: Tu namespace es `App` a secas, porque lo pusiste en el classmap en lugar del psr-4

Answer (score 0):

Actualizaste el namespace de Controller? Si no lo hiciste quizas es eso. Intenta poner un poco de codigo cuando pidas ayuda para saber exactamente cual es el problema. Saludos

Sería de pasar este namespace `namespace app\Http\Controllers` a `namespace app\Http\Controllers\Admin`